Handling py_canoe in a multi-thread environment
I am trying to implement a tool that executes some commands in CANoe, using for that the py_canoe library. If I implement all the CANoe calls in the main thread everything works fine, but since some of them take a lot of time (highest being 4 mins) I want to execute it a parallel thread and keep the main one only for GUI updates.
When I do this, I can see some strange cases where the CANoe execution stops after opening the instance, depending on the machine I execute the tool on, being a sporadic issue. As a hint, I'm using pySimpleGUI for the UI and I use the built-in thread implementation, but I have already tried to code it myself and the result is the same.
I don't see whether this library is thread safe or not in the documentation, so I'm assuming it's not, and that's why I am having such problems.
Has anyone seen anything similar? Is anyone executing this library in a GUI or multi-thread application? If so, how?
This is an example of my code:
Pd_conf.MainWindow.perform_long_operation(func=lambda: execute_smoketests(choice), end_key="--PRECONDITION_CHECK_DONE--")
    event, values = Pd_conf.MainWindow.read(timeout=0)
    event = None
    print(f"TARGET   : Execute the following smoke tests: {choice}")
    print(f"Duration : 0:00:00")  # noqa: F541
    timeDelta = 0
    compileStart = datetime.now()
    while event != "--PRECONDITION_CHECK_DONE--":
        event, values = Pd_conf.MainWindow.read(timeout=1000)
        if (datetime.now() - compileStart).seconds > timeDelta:
            # Get time delta since start of CANoe operation
            timeDelta = (datetime.now() - compileStart).seconds
            # Update print output if one second has passed
            print(f"Duration : {timedelta(seconds=timeDelta)}", replace=f"Duration : {timedelta(seconds=timeDelta-1)}")

Thanks in advance!
I was expecting a way of handling py_canoe library from a different thread or at least with a GUI in the application

Not sure anything wrong from your code
Demo script here for yur reference
from random import randint
import time, datetime
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def execute_smoketests(choice):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    # simulate the smoke tests
    delay = randint(2000, 5000)/1000
    time.sleep(delay)
    delta = datetime.datetime.now() - now
    return choice, delta

start_key = "Precondition Check"
end_key = "--PRECONDITION_CHECK_DONE--"

layout = [
    [sg.Radio(f"Test {i}", "TEST", default=(i==0), key=("Test", i)) for i in range(5)],
    [sg.Text("", expand_x=True, key="S1")],
    [sg.Text("", expand_x=True, key="S2")],
    [sg.Button(start_key, expand_x=True)],
]
window = sg.Window("CANoe", layout)
timeout, running = None, False

while True:

    event, values = window.read(timeout=timeout)

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    elif event == start_key and not running:
        for choice in range(5):
            if values[("Test", choice)]:
                break
        count_now = datetime.datetime.now()
        timeout, running = 10, True
        window["S1"].update(f"Executing the following smoke tests: {choice}")
        window.perform_long_operation(func=lambda:execute_smoketests(choice), end_key=end_key)

    elif event == sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT and running:
        count_delta = datetime.datetime.now() - count_now
        window["S2"].update(f"Duration : {str(count_delta)}")

    elif event == end_key:
        timeout, running = None, False
        choice, delta = values[end_key]
        window["S1"].update(f"Executed the following smoke tests: {choice}")
        window["S2"].update(f"Duration : {str(delta)}")

window.close()





I think that the main issue is using py_canoe calls within the function executed in the worker thread. So I was wondering if someone found other way or if there is something mandatory before doing that with py_canoe library

So above code work for you, or not ? If not, what wrong or what exception you have ?

It does work for me. When I include the library calls I get the typical error: "main thread is not in main loop"

IMPORTANT! The first thing to understand with threading in PySimpleGUI (the tkinter port in particular) is that you must not make any calls into PySimpleGUI from a thread that are GUI related... with one exception: window.write_event_value. Regardless of how you start your thread, you have the same restriction, you must not make any calls to PySimpleGUI from your thread, except for write_event_value.

I have no GUI calls in the thread, only py_canoe calls

IMO, there should be statements not in the main thread to update the GUI ! I cannot find it for you for no code there.
